# Admin access when the admin password has changed in AD

Tags: security

I have a demo/test (luckily) build of Sharepoint 2013 running on a server in-house. 
When I set it up it asked me to allocate a domain user as the admin, I use my own domain admin account (from Active Directory).

Since this, I have changed my password in AD.
And I cannot change it back to the one I had before due to password policy.

Now trying to access sharepoint, it just gives a 503 error.
And vent viewer on the server logs an Audit Failure "Unknown user name or bad password"

So how can I change either the user/password that sharepoint is using, or change just the password that it is using?

Comment: Looks like you have set your own domain account as farm admin. Are the same account running everything else? (Sql, applications pool and services? If so i dont think that the trouble to change account would be worth it. But if you need to i would suggest to set your password to the old one and then try to change your account to another account where you dont have to follow the password policy. https://theblobfarm.wordpress.com/2014/07/09/changing-the-sharepoint-farm-account-from-a-non-domain-to-a-domain-account/

Comment: Most probably, your application pool is running under that user and you have hard-coded the credentials. You should check that first.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need and an option to change the password just for SharePoint. Make sure you can ping to the domain controller from SP machine or the other way around. This is to ensure the connectivity is there.

503 is for [Service Unavailable](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E503.html). Therefore the connectivity between machines must be checked.

Comment: The 503 is coming from IIS on the sharepoint server, which is also running a local SQL server.
Event viewer shows "Audit failure" - Unknown user name or bad password.